# How to read an feature class through an enterprise geodatabase connection with geopandas?

Tags: python, geopandas, esri-geodatabase

I want to create a readable dataframe using geopandas from an ArcGIS versioned geodatabase through an SDE Connection File. Is this possible? GeoPandas won't read the output that I've used with arcpy in the past. In the below code, for example, I can use prod_parcels for arcpy.ListFields() or other code.

What kind of manipulation is needed to access the SDE data as a dataframe?

```
# Set input variables
# set workspace folder
ws = r"D:\TestData\Testing"
# Geodatabase with FME feature class
fme_gdb = r"D:\TestData\Testing\TestEnvironment.gdb"
#FME feature class name
fme_fc_name = ""
# Path to FME feature class
fme_fc = os.path.join(fme_gdb, fme_fc_name)
# Production parcels
sdeMx = arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management(ws, 'tempMxServ.sde', \
                                        'ORACLE', server,\
                                        'DATABASE_AUTH', username, \
                                        password,'SAVE_USERNAME')
# Prod parcel feature class
prod_parcels = sdeMx.getOutput(0) + "filename"
# # Open prod parcels as geo dataframe
prod_gdf = geopandas.read_file(prod_parcels, usecols=['COUNTY_NAME'])
```

Comment: You need to use a DA SearchCursor to generate a list-of-lists, then put that in Pandas

Comment: @Vince Basically creating a list of lists where each interior list is a field name + values? I have several million parcels so believe that would end up taking pretty long to generate.

Comment: I can cache 3.5M features with dozens of fields via a DA Search Cursor from PostgreSQL in 32 seconds. The result is a list of field values { {row1col1,row1col2}, {row2col1,row2col2},...} for whatever columns are queried (in the field list for the SearchCursor).